# How do I printf a phrase on a certain probability?

Tags: c, probability

So I’m trying to create a buy and sell program and in there, I also coded the range where a random price out of a certain range will pop out. Now the problem is I can’t  figure out a way on how to display a “not available today” on a 15% chance. so basically the price list will only show the price of the item OR a “not available today” note.

```
this is how the code looks like now. i only inserted the price range and an srand function.


srand(time(NULL));
item1 = rand() % (1000 - 500 + 1) + 500;
item2 = rand() % (5000 - 1500 + 1) + 1500;
item3 = rand() % ( 8000 - 5000 + 1 ) + 5000;

  printf("The Price of Item1 is %dG\n", item1);
  printf("The Price of Item2 is %dG\n", item2);
  printf("The Price of Item3 is %dG\n", item3);
```

Comment: learn about `if` in C https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-if-else-statement

Comment: It's unclear how you want your "buy and sell program" to work.  Please [Edit] your post.  Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.  SUGGESTION: look at these examples of "pseudo code": https://www.unf.edu/~broggio/cop2221/2221pseu.htm

Comment: @paulsm4 my only concern is how do i get to print out “not available” on a 15 percent probability instead of the price  sorry for confusion 

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((rand()%(100)+1) <= 15 ) {
    printf("Item not available today\n");
} else {
    printf("The Price of Item1 is %dG\n", item1);
}
```

Could this be a simple implementation of what you are trying to do?

Edit: fixed rand()

Comment: Wrong. `rand() % (100 - 15 +1)` will return numbers within this range: `0..85`

Comment: does the 15 outside the rand equation represent the probability? and i tried to code it but it does not show the prices at all now.. im sorry for having many questions 

Comment: @aewinter This code is wrong

Comment: rand()%(100-15+1)+15) will always be 15+

Comment: @aewinter sorry I did it too quick I'm editing it

Comment: @0___________ Sorry, nitpicking again: *will always be 15+* - wrong. It can be 15 in some small fraction of cases, as `rand() % (100 - 15 +1)` can result in 0 as well.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs 15+ means 15 or more

Comment: @0___________ Right, apologies

Answer (score -1):

```
if(rand() % 100 > 15)
{
    /* more than 15 */
}
else
{
    /* less or equal 15 */
}
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `>=`. `rand() % 100` returns `0..99`. And it wasn't me who gave you -1.

Comment: where am i supposed to input the price range now? thank you for answering 

Comment: @aewinter What the price range has to do with 15% probability?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs because originally in the program the specific area there shows a random price based on the price range. it’s either that or the not available today phrase which can come out with 15% probability.

Comment: @aewinter And? The answer is already present in code snippets provided by people.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs i was just confused since in the code snippets the price range i showed was removed and when i coded the provided coded and added my price range, it wasn’t working. sorry.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I did, this code implements a 16-84% probability

Comment: @aewinter what didn't work?

Comment: @emetsipe *this code implements a 16-84% probability* - wrong. This code implements a 16% probability. If `>` is replaced `>=` this would give you 15% probability.

Comment: that's what I said, 16/84. it wasn't a minus or idk what you thought I said. I meant a 16% prob. to show no product and a 84% to show the product

Comment: @emetsipe Ah, yes, I misunderstood what you meant by 16-84. Correct.

Comment: @aewinter you would have to do one loop for each product; else if you put them all in one, when the product is not available it won't show the others too